# Flash content not showing - how do I set the path?

Tags: xml, flash, swfobject

I am displaying some flash content on a fairly standard page. This works really well when the flash, xml file and html page are sitting together in the same directory.

See working example: http://www.rouviere.com/flipbook/

However, I want to display that same content in another page which is deeper inside the site but outside of the directory that houses the .swf and .xml files as well as the assets.

Here is the page that I would like the content to show up properly on: http://www.rouviere.com/writing/books

Here are the parameters that I have set:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../flipbook/swfobject.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../flipbook/swfaddress.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {
xmlPath:          '../../flipbook/setup.xml',
preloaderMessage: 'LOADING XML',
title:            'Books | Rouviere Media' 
};

var params = {};
var attributes = {id:'flipbook', name:'flipbook'};
params.scale = "noscale";
params.salign = "tl";
params.bgcolor = "0x000000";
params.allowfullscreen = "true";
params.allowScriptAccess = "always";

swfobject.embedSWF("../../flipbook/preview.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

The js files are loading properly but the flash content is not, so I could use a little help getting that sorted out.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the HTML on public? I just want to see the whole HTML so that I can check what's wrong with it.

Comment: You can see the html source for both URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try insert the swfobject code within

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     //Put your code here
    })
```

I also noticed that the links on /flipbook/setup.xml is relative to /flipbook/ you need to make it absolute so that it can be used on both pages.

At the moment the flash stopped when it tries to load http://www.rouviere.com/writing/pages/tam_01.jpg since the app expects an image file where that url is returning webpage.

Comment: ysrb, I only need the content to show up on http://www.rouviere.com/writing/books

Comment: @fmz yes buy it seems that the flash needs to load the image and it fails to load the image because the reference is incorrect.

Comment: so if the page is /root/writing/books/ and the xml file is /root/flipbook/ what would the correct path be?

Comment: The path of the xml, swf, and js files are correct. The one you need to change is the path inside the setup.xml because it is using relative path. You ne to change eg. instead of pages/tam_01.jpg you need to put /flipbook/pages/tam_01.jpg

Comment: Ok. Got it. It now shows up correctly in Safari, but it doesn't show up in Firefox. I am guessing a cache issue. But thanks for the help!

Comment: @fmz i think you need to remove the $(document).ready(function(){
 code. I thought you have jquery and it seems that you did not include jquery library and it throws error on firefox

Comment: @fmz i can see it in firefox now. but you need to increase the height of the div. I tried in line styling it 1000px and I can see the flash.

Comment: @fmz try changing the div to <div class="clearfix" id="main" style="height: 800px;">

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the preview.swf fails to find and load the XML file.

By default, Flash Player resolves paths relative to the presenting HTML page, not relative to where the swf file is. You can probably make relative paths work, but i would recommend using full paths from the root of the server, when possible, like:

```
xmlPath: '/flipbook/setup.xml'
```

... instead of:

```
xmlPath: '../../flipbook/setup.xml'
```

Another possible solution is to use the base parameter, to tell Flash Player what path to use as base, like:

```
xmlPath: 'setup.xml'
...
params.base = '/flipbook/'
```